# FragmentManager IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, fragment

My function:

```
private void  buildEmptyLessonList()
{
    final Context ctx = this;

    LinearLayout topContainer = findViewById(R.id.LessonList);
    topContainer.removeAllViews();
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams llparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ScrollView svContainer = new ScrollView(ctx);
    svContainer.setLayoutParams(llparams);
    topContainer.addView(svContainer);

    LinearLayout tl = new LinearLayout(ctx);
    tl.setId(generateViewId());
    tl.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    tl.setLayoutParams(llparams);
    svContainer.addView(tl);
    ft.add(tl.getId(), NoLessons.newInstance(), "NoLessons");
    ft.commit();

        //getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
}
```

If I very often (faster than once per second) call this function, I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:987)
  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1171)
  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run (BackStackRecord.java:815)
  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions (FragmentManager.java:1582)
  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run (FragmentManager.java:483)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6692)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1468)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Using "getChildFragmentTransaction()" does not give any effect.

Comment: This is not exact error, just bottom of this error, there will be message exception and line no. to locate your Exception

Comment: You have imported app.Fragment or v4.app.Fragment

Comment: Does the exception have a message?

Comment: The error does not give me the line number. The application just crashes, and throws out just such an exception: (